# How do to pass tag of UIView pressed to method selector?

Tags: iphone, uiview, selector, uigesturerecognizer

I have 11 UIView on each has been set a Gesture Recognizer. This UIView are within mutable array and each have got a tag. How do to pass tag of UIView pressed to method selector?

```
viewIcone.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
viewIcone.tag = index;    

UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(touchUp:)];
tap.delegate = self;
[viewIcone addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[self.arrayMutabile insertObject:viewIcone atIndex:index];

[self addSubview:viewIcone];
```

The implementation of method selector is:

```
-(void) touchUp: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer{

   NSInteger tag = [self.arrayMutabile indexOfObject:self.viewIcone];
   NSLog(@"the tag is %d", tag);
}
```

I always leave 10. Where is the wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The UITapGestureRecognizer has a view property which it inherits from it's parent:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer

```
The view the gesture recognizer is attached to. (read-only)

@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *view
Discussion
You attach (or add) a gesture recognizer to a UIView object using the addGestureRecognizer: method.

Availability
Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
Declared In
UIGestureRecognizer.h
```

This will be the view that was tapped and you can retrieve the tag from there.

Comment: Did this help?  If so you should accept the answer, if not I can expand upon it.